# Github forking new version and merging changes with it

Tags: git, github

Question about standard git/github workflow procedure I think. But I really understand all that stuff very badly.

1. A month ago I had forked some project.
2. I made my branches with
   changes I need
3. Original project has changed since
4. I want to fork new version and add changes that I've made to previous version

How should I do this? The problems I faced:

1) I can not fork new version, when I press fork github redirects me to my current fork of new version, do I have to remove it to have new version?

2) Is it possible some how to apply changes I've made to previous version in some automatically manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to fetch upstream.

```
$ git remote add upstream git@github.com:original-user/project-name.git
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b merge-upstream
$ git fetch upstream
$ git merge upstream/master
```

At this point, you have the new version on a branch named `merge-upstream`. If everything still works from here, you'll want to merge this to your master.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge merge-upstream
```

Now your `master` should be all good with the original master. Delete your working branch.

```
$ git branch -d merge-upstream
```

You now have a copy. So you can test your changes against the new `master`. Merge `master` into your branch to test.

```
$ git checkout my-feature
$ git merge master
```

You should now have all of the changes from the original user's master branch merged into your feature branch.

PS: When working on a long-running project, I try to make sure the original master doesn't get more than a day or two ahead of me. In fact, I always add the remote `upstream` to point to the original user's repository. Then I can pull in upstream changes whenever I need them.